# Python: Converting a Cesar Cipher to an Affine Cipher

Tags: python, encryption, caesar-cipher

I am supposed to convert this Cesar Cipher into an Affine Cipher, but unfortunately can not seem to figure it out.

Ultimately I am supposed to convert the given Cesar Cipher code I have into an Affine Cipher that deciphers any string cipher text made up of the 26 lowercase letters {a, b, c, …, x, y, z}. This does so via a brute force search, trying all possible keys and should output the encryption key k =(a, b) and the corresponding plain text. The program should stop when an “understandable” plain text message is decrypted.

Any help pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Here is the Cesar Cipher code:

```
def caeser (s, k):
    y = ""
    for x in s:
        c = ((ord(x) - ord("a")) + k) % 26
        y = y + chr(ord("a") + c)
    return y

def topLetter(s):
    count = [0]*26
    for x in s:
        x_index = (ord(x) - ord("a"))
        count[x_index] += 1
    lcount = 0
lchar = ""
for i in range(26):
    if count[i] > lcount:
        lcount = count[i]
        lchar = chr(i + ord('a'))
return lchar

def findShift(s):
    return(ord(topLetter(s)) - ord("e"))

cipher = "vwduwljudeehghyhubwklqjlfrxogilqgsohdvhuhwxuqdqbeoxhsulqwviruydxowdqgdodupghvljqedvhgrqzklfkedqnbrxghflghrqldpvhwwlqjxsvdihkrxvhfr"
print("Deciphering:'", cipher +"'")

print("\nBrute Force")
shift = 1
while shift < 26:
    ptext = caeser(cipher, -1*shift)
    print()
    print("Plaintext message when encryption key =", shift)
    print(ptext)
    shift += 1
```

Here is some sample output to help you guys out.

```
Decrypting the cipher text: 'vwduwljudeehghyhubwklqjlfrxogilqgsohdvhuhwxuqdqbeoxhsulqwviruydxowdqgdodupghvljqedvhgrqzklfkedqnbrxghflghrqldpvhwwlqjxsvdihkrxvhfr'

Encryption key: a = 1 b = 1
Decryption equation: x = 1 *(y - 1)

Plaintext:
uvctvkitcddgfgxgtavjkpikeqwnfhkpfrngcugtgvwtpcpadnwgrtkpvuhqtxcwnvcpfcnctofgukipdcugfqpyjkejdcpmaqwfgekfgqpkcougvvkpiwruchgjqwugeq

Hit enter to continue search or 'S' key to stop: 
Encryption key: a = 3 b = 1
Decryption equation: x = 9 *(y - 1)

Plaintext:
yhsphmupsbbctczcpahdmfumkoqntlmftxncsycpchqpfsfabnqcxpmfhylopzsqnhsftsnspwtcymufbsyctofidmkdbsfeaoqtckmtcofmswychhmfuqxyslcdoqycko

Hit enter to continue search or 'S' key to stop: 
Encryption key: a = 5 b = 1
Decryption equation: x = 21 *(y - 1)
```

Comment: @SeanBallais I have been trying to figure out the ins and outs of the Cesar Cipher so I understand it enough to try to convert it to an Affine Cipher. Also trying my best to fully understand an Affine Cipher and what I need to do.

Comment: Here is an explanation of the Caesar cipher: write down the alphabet, from a to z, twice in succession: abc..zabc..z. Now, on the next line, count over `k` positions (whatever value you choose) from the first 'a', and write the alphabet once from a to z. For example, if your `k` was 11, you would count over 11 positions, and the 'a' on the second line would be beneath the 'l' (ell) of the alphabet on the first line. Now run the cipher by finding each character of your sentence in the bottom row, and replacing it with the corresponding character from the top row.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking here (as opposed to what your homework assignment is). Are you confused about what an affine cipher is? Or about how to integrate it into your brute force cracking program? Or do you not understand the code you already have somehow?

Comment: @Blckknght I would say more so the how to integrate it part.

Answer (score 0):

There are two major differences between the caesar cipher brute force solver you already have and what you'll need to write to brute force an affine cipher.

The first change is that the key for an affine cipher is two integers (often named `a` and `b`) rather than just a single value in a caesar cipher. (An affine cipher with `a` equal to `1` is equivalent to a casear cipher with key `b`.) The value used as `a` must be coprime with the length of the alphabet, which for the 26 lowercase letters means it must be an odd number between 1 and 25 (inclusive) other than 13. The `b` value is just like the key to a caesar cipher, so any integer works, though since the cipher's computation uses modular arithmetic, values that differ by a multiple of the alphabet length are equivalent. I'd stick to values between 0 and 25 for your code that operates on lowercase letters. Your brute force code will need to generate both parts of the keys (probably with nested loops, though `itertools.product` could work too).

The second change is that reversing encryption to get decryption is more complicated with an affine cypher. While a caesar cipher's decrpytion key is simply the encryption key negated, figuring out the decryption version an affine cypher's key requires more computation. If you encrypt with the key (`a`, `b`), you want to decrypt with the key (`a`<sup>-1</sup>, `-b`*`a`<sup>-1</sup>), where `a`<sup>-1</sup> is the [modular multiplicative inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) of `a` with respect to the alphabet size. You'll probably want to write code to compute such inverses for your solver, though you could just brute force the decryption key and not care about the encryption key that was used originally if you want.